# How to rotate rasters with GDAL, QGIS or GRASS GIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, grass-gis, rotate, trmm

I need to rotate raster files from the [TRMM Multisatellite Precipitation monthly product 3B43](https://pmm.nasa.gov/data-access/downloads/TRMM). For some unknown reason, this data comes rotated 90 degrees clockwise, meaning that the y coordinate is the x and that the x coordinate is the y.

Of the few proposed solutions which can be found online, none worked:

- [hdp dumpsds](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Import_TRMM) -  `hdp dumpsds -r 4 -d -o outfile -b 3B43.20000501.7A.HDF.nc`
  error: SDS with reference number 1: not found
- [Use ENVI](https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/information/faqs?title=How%20can%20I%20import%20and%20geolocate%20the%200.1-degree%20resolution%20IMERG%20native%20HDF5%20file%20in%20ENVI%3F#) - can't use/don't have ENVI.
- [CDO](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/boards/2/topics/102) specifying a target grid - This approach almost worked, however  while the data extent is correctly transformed (i.e., x and y are swapped), the pixels are placed randomly. My target grid specification are:

  gridtype = lonlat

  xsize = 1440 # replace by your value

  ysize = 720 # replace by your value

  xfirst = -179 # replace by your value

  xinc = 0.25 # replace by your value

  yfirst = -89.5 # replace by your value

  yinc = 0.25 # replace by your value

  Then run the commands:

> ```
> cdo setgridtype,curvilinear  3B43.20000501.7A.HDF.nc out.nc
> cdo remapbil,target_grid.txt out.nc out2.nc
> ```

Comment: In addition, there is the GRASS GIS Addon https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/i.rotate.html

Comment: The issue with GRASS GIS is that, latitude being longitude, TRMM rasters would likely exceed 90 degrees of latitude (true in my case), therefore you would need extra work to first create a mapset in a customized location where to import the rasters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @xunilk, your answers put me in the right direction, I ended up simply swapping X and Y in the `geotransform` output.

```py
from osgeo import gdal, osr 
import numpy as np 
import glob, os, errno

try:
    os.makedirs("./rotated/") except OSError as e:
    if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise

nclist = [f for f in glob.glob("*.nc")]

for nc in nclist:
    #Load .nc raster files and extract precipitation band
    dataset = gdal.Open("NETCDF:{0}:{1}".format(nc, "precipitation"))
    band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
    array = dataset.ReadAsArray()
    geot = dataset.GetGeoTransform()
    #The trick is here, swap x and y
    geotr = geot[3:6] + geot[0:3]
    wkt = dataset.GetProjection()
    # Create gtif file
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
    output_name = os.path.splitext(nc)[0]
    output_file = os.path.join("./rotated", output_name + "." + "tiff")
    dst_ds = driver.Create(output_file,
                       band.XSize,
                       band.YSize,
                       1,
                       gdal.GDT_Float32)
    array_rot = np.array(array_rot)
    #writting output raster
    dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray( array_rot )
    #setting extension of output raster
    #top left x, w-e pixel resolution, rotation, top left y, rotation, n-s pixel resolution
    dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotr)
    # setting spatial reference of output raster
    srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    srs.ImportFromWkt(wkt)
    dst_ds.SetProjection( srs.ExportToWkt() )
    #Close output raster dataset
    dataset = None
```

I adapted the function to load .nc rasters, as my question was on how to process TRMM precipitation data which comes in .nc format.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a python script by using an algorithm for rotating 90 degrees clockwise a matrix. I took one from this link:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rotate-a-matrix-by-90-degree-in-clockwise-direction-without-using-any-extra-space/

So, I developed following code, with GDAL python module, for producing rotated raster.

```
def rotate90Clockwise(A): 
    N = len(A[0]) 
    for i in range(N // 2): 
        for j in range(i, N - i - 1): 
            temp = A[i][j] 
            A[i][j] = A[N - 1 - j][i] 
            A[N - 1 - j][i] = A[N - 1 - i][N - 1 - j] 
            A[N - 1 - i][N - 1 - j] = A[j][N - 1 - i] 
            A[j][N - 1 - i] = temp 

from osgeo import gdal, osr
import numpy as np

dataset = gdal.Open("/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/test_0_5_0_5_clip.tif")
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)

array = dataset.ReadAsArray()

rotate90Clockwise(array) 

N = len(array[0])

array_rot = [ array[i] for i in range(N) ]

geotransform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()
wkt = dataset.GetProjection()

# Create gtif file
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
output_file = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/rotated_raster.tif"

dst_ds = driver.Create(output_file,
                       band.XSize,
                       band.YSize,
                       1,
                       gdal.GDT_Float32)

array_rot = np.array(array_rot)

#writting output raster
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray( array_rot )
#setting extension of output raster
# top left x, w-e pixel resolution, rotation, top left y, rotation, n-s pixel resolution
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
# setting spatial reference of output raster
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromWkt(wkt)
dst_ds.SetProjection( srs.ExportToWkt() )
#Close output raster dataset

dataset = None
dst_ds = None
```

I ran above code with a raster with random values between 1 and 1000. Resulting rotated raster is also showed in following image. Value for (0,3) pixel in original raster is 950 (corroborated with Value Tool QGIS plugin).

[image]

Same value is in (3,19) pixel of rotated raster in following image. However, I tested for other values and results were always as expected.

[image]

**Editing Note:**

I had a misunderstanding in my previous code. If for some unknown reason this data comes rotated 90 degrees clockwise, to fix it is rotating in anticlockwise sense. So, I found out an alternative algorithm for rotating 90 degrees anticlockwise a matrix in following link:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141689/rotate-matrix-using-python/141788#141788

So, my code is now more concise:

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr
import numpy as np

dataset = gdal.Open("/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/test_0_5_0_5_clip.tif")
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)

array = dataset.ReadAsArray()

#rotate raster 90 degrees anticlockwise
array_rot = (list(list(x) for x in zip(*matrix))[::-1])

geotransform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()
wkt = dataset.GetProjection()

# Create gtif file
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
output_file = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/rotated_raster.tif"

dst_ds = driver.Create(output_file,
                       band.XSize,
                       band.YSize,
                       1,
                       gdal.GDT_Float32)

array_rot = np.array(array_rot)

#writting output raster
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray( array_rot )
#setting extension of output raster
# top left x, w-e pixel resolution, rotation, top left y, rotation, n-s pixel resolution
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
# setting spatial reference of output raster
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromWkt(wkt)
dst_ds.SetProjection( srs.ExportToWkt() )
#Close output raster dataset

dataset = None
dst_ds = None
```